# How to clear all the local storage input fields while we submit the form

Tags: vue.js

Here I am using vue.js local storage in my vue method. Here everything is fine like auto saving the form data in local storage but the issue is while I am submitting the form the data is not clearing still it is displaying the old data in form fields. so I am trying to achieve here is while we submit the form i want to clear the auto save form data. So how can we do that in vue.js

*html***

```
<div>
    <input type="text" v-model="category" placeholder="Search your category">
    <input type="text" v-model="title" placeholder="Search your category">
    <input type="text" v-model="address" placeholder="Search your category">
    <input type="text" v-model="city" placeholder="Search your category">
    <input type="text" v-model="state" placeholder="Search your category">
    <input type="text" v-model="zip" placeholder="Search your category">
    <input type="text" v-model="price" placeholder="Search your category">
    <input type="text" v-model="description" placeholder="Search your category">
    <button id="buttonDemo" @click.prevent="next()">Next</button>
</div>
```

```
mounted: function () {
    if (localStorage.category) {
      this.category = localStorage.category;
    }
    if (localStorage.title) {
      this.title = localStorage.title;
    }
    if (localStorage.address) {
      this.address = localStorage.address;
    }
    if (localStorage.city) {
      this.city = localStorage.city;
    }
    if (localStorage.state) {
      this.state = localStorage.state;
    }
    if (localStorage.zip) {
      this.zip = localStorage.zip;
    }
    if (localStorage.price) {
      this.price = localStorage.price;
    }
    if (localStorage.description) {
      this.description = localStorage.description;
    }
}
```

```
methods() {
     localStorage.category = this.category;
      localStorage.title = this.title;
      localStorage.address = this.address;
      localStorage.city = this.city;
      localStorage.state = this.state;
      localStorage.zip = this.zip;
      localStorage.price = this.price;
      localStorage.description = this.description;
      
      submitForm: function(){
            axios({
                method : "POST",
                url: "{% url 'PostAd' %}", //django path name
                headers: {'X-CSRFTOKEN': '{{ csrf_token }}', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                data : {"category":this.category, "title":this.title,
                "address":this.address,
                "city": this.city,
                "state": this.state,
                "zip": this.zip,
                "price": this.price,
                "description": this.description,
                "radio_price": this.radio_price,
                "Job_title": this.model,
                },//data
              }).then(response => {
              console.log("response");
              console.log(response.data);
                  this.success_msg = response.data['msg'];
                 window.location.replace('{% url "classifieds" %}')  // Replace home by the name of your home view

              }).catch(err => {
                     this.err_msg = err.response.data['err'];
              console.log("response1");
              console.log(err.response.data);

              });

          },

  },

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set those `localStorage` fields to empty strings in `submitForm()`:

```js
methods() {
  submitForm: function() {
    axios({
      /*...*/
    }).then(response => {
      localStorage.category = '';
      localStorage.title = '';
      localStorage.address = '';
      localStorage.city = '';
      localStorage.state = '';
      localStorage.zip = '';
      localStorage.price = '';
      localStorage.description = '';
      this.category = '';
      this.title = '';
      this.address = '';
      this.city = '';
      this.state = '';
      this.zip = '';
      this.price = '';
      this.description = '';

      /*...*/
    }).catch(error => {
      /*...*/
    })
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From MDN docs on [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), use:

```js
localStorage.clear()
```

This still won't reset your vue data until the page is refreshed. You will have to do that separately.